# Firebase on Android Studio (LoginScreen)

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

So I'm trying to create a login screen for my app in java on Android Studio using Firebase. Currently, in creating accounts, I am doing it this way:

```
if (password.getText().toString().equals(confirm.getText().toString())) {
    Map map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put(username.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
    myFirebaseRef.push().setValue(map);
    error.setText("Account created!");
}
else {
   error.setText("Passwords do not match");
}
```

But it saves the data on my Firebase like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAljf.png)

So now on my login screen, once a user types in their username, I wanna search my Firebase for the username, and make sure it exists, then see if the password matches what they entered. How Would I do that? Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't save your users password in human readable text to your database.
To create a user with password and password, you could create a custom object with these values and save it to your firebase.

Comment: But if I did it my way, how would I access the data?

Comment: You do not save any relation between the username and the password, so simply, you can't to it in your way.

Comment: how would I access the map though?

Comment: Please consider reading the firebase guide for android, found here: [Understanding Data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/understanding-data.html)
To retrieve data: `myFirebaseRef.getRef().getAuth().getAuth().entrySet()`

Answer (score 1):

As Amy already said: no matter what else you do, immediately change your code to **stop storing passwords in plain text**. That is an incredibly bad practice. In general authentication is better left to dedicated tools, such as [Firebase Authentication](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/user-auth.html).

Aside from that, you'll want to change the way you store the users a bit. It seems you identify users by their name, store them under their name:

```
Map map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put(username.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
myFirebaseRef.updateChildren(map);
```

Now you can look up a user by their name with:

```
Firebase userRef = myFirebaseRef.child(username.getText().toString());
userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...
```

See the [Firebase guide on reading data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html) for more on that.

Comment: ok thanks but how would I continue with looking up a user by their username? I'm trying to do this on a button click but in the tutorial it does it whenever the data in firebase is changed

Comment: I'm not sure what more you're looking for here. The second snippet of code in my answer looks up a user by their name if you use the first snippet to set them. So: use these snippets instead of what you have and you'll be set. If this isn't what you're looking for, it is unclear (to me at least) what you're looking for.

Comment: You included a "..." in your answer and idk how to continue with that. could you write a full code for me?

Comment: I included a link to the guide that documents how to implement the listener.